# Simple horizontal line graph in php

Tags: php, mysql, css

Three values that generates dynamically with php and mysql
 
home team chance : 45
draw chance : 30 
away team chance 25
total 100(100%)

now i need to draw horizontal line graph (example below) with these values

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/210/graphaw.jpg/

how do i draw this, I am looking for your help.

Comment: Take a look at these functions: http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php ;-))

Comment: you could take a graph library like JPGraph or Google Chart API or event something else. Try google "PHP Graph"

Comment: you should use javascript and canvas for this type of things...

Answer (score 0):

PHP GD might be the right thing for you. Good luck!

http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

Answer (score 0):

I had previous experience with this and it ended up stressing the server when multiple charts have to be rendered when there are many users.

You should do this with html5 canvas or svg, etc.

There are couple good ones.

For an actual chart, check out the jquery plugin "flot".

Othwerise, check out whatever is offered in jqueryui.com